# Add a string parameter to an AudioUnit

Tags: string, macos, parameters, audiounit

For instance, this AudioUnit has to connect to a host through the network, and the hostname has to be configured in a Cocoa View, and has to be saved so that reloading the project restores the hostname.

How would you do that (interface + parameter saving, apart from the network thing of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `SaveState()` and `RestoreState()` methods in your AudioUnit.  These functions will be called when the sequencer saves and opens a document, respectively, and give you the chance to store data alongside a particular plugin instance.

The definition for these functions can be found in the file `AUBase.h` in the AudioUnit SDK.

Comment: Indeed, http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2008/Feb/msg00112.html says the same thing.

Comment: Seems that http://code.google.com/p/vstau/source/browse/trunk/VSTAU.cpp shows a good example in VSTAU::SaveState and VSTAU::RestoreState, for storing whole (VST) chunks in AU's document storage.

Comment: But how would you send the NSString from the CocoaView to the AudioUnit Kernel?

Comment: Answer: maybe use the Properties instead of the Parameters see http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4169706&sid=27064441ff62205844e893a9d82b5007#4169706

Comment: But how would you send the NSString (or anything else) from the AudioUnit Kernel to the CocoaView?

Comment: @moala, you should make that a separate question... it's kind of O/T here. :)

Comment: Anyway, I have the answer: use Audio Unit's Properties (AudioUnitGetProperty, AudioUnitSetProperty), event notification (PropertyChanged) and AudioUnitEvent listeners (AUEventListenerCreate). See CoreAudio's Audio Unit Filter example for instance for a model.